# How to make Windows tooltip stay longer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

Is there any way to increase/decrease timeout of mouse-over tooltip (time it stays on the page until mouse pointer moved/button clicked)?

I found some help to disable them entirely or increase time till they appear, but I just want to be able to read long tooltips in peace.

Maybe through editing registry or group policies?
I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method, but it is not a registry edit. The amount of time the tool tip stays up is set to ten times the double click speed by default. Not the best solution, but it'll give you some time. Also, if you decrease the MouseHoverTime value to 1 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Mouse, you can get the tooltip to come back faster, even if it doesn't stay around as long. Sorry I don't know a better way.